# Java How do I create a unique object name?

Tags: java, class, object, user-input

How would I go about creating a unique object every time a **user** wants to create a new account?

> For example if user makes an account I would like an object named **acc1** then if a user makes another account i would like the object named acc2.
>   `Account ac = new Account(input.nextInt(),0,0);`. This is around where i need it to happen.

I tried keeping the code as simplistic as possible and also note I'm rather new to java and this is a personal project just to learn.

```
 System.out.println("Welcome to JAVA Bank");
    System.out.println("____________________");
    System.out.println("Plese Choose an Option: ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("(1) New Account");
    System.out.println("(2) Enter Existing Account");



    int choice = input.nextInt();


    switch(choice){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please choose an Account ID#");
            Account ac = new Account(input.nextInt(),0,0);
            break;




public class Account {

private int id = 0;
private double balance = 0;
private double annualInterestRate = 0;
private Date dateCreated;

public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    this.dateCreated = new Date();

}
```

Help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of Java Collections?

Comment: I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @David -- then get familiar with it!  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/  Your stated goal is to learn Java.

Comment: @PM77-1  -- Will do thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting a unique way of identifying multiple Accounts perhaps a HashMap is the way to go. A HashMap stores key-value pairs where each key is unique.

Create a class level variable to store the accounts:

```
Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<String, Account>();
```

Create/Add account to HashMap:

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("Please choose an Account ID#");
    int accountID = input.nextInt(); //Get the requested ID
    if (accounts.containsKey("acc"+accountID) //Check to see if an account already has this ID (I added acc to the start of each account but it is optional)
    {
       //Tell user the account ID is in use already and then stop
       System.out.println("Account: " + accountID + " already exists!");
       break;
    }

        //Create account and add it to the HashMap using the unique identifier key
        Account ac = new Account(input.nextInt(),0,0);
        accounts.put("acc"+accountID, ac);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear simple answer with comments. I'll give it a try and see how it works out for what I'm trying to accomplish. So every time an account is made it recieves a unique ID via hashmap? How would I access it via that ID if there are multiple? Or should I access via my class ID?

Comment: You can access the account through accounts.get ("acc"+ID);. Note that if the account doesn't exist, it will return null instead of an account.

Comment: Where do i insert Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<String, Account>(); ????? I tried putting it everywhere and it doesn't work. It says cannot find symbol Class: Map. I tried putting it in my class, different methods, in main, and i improted util.hashMap and nothing works

Comment: I tried adding Hash to it. I tried inserting it everywhere. It does not work at all

Comment: Did you import util.HashMap or java.util.HashMap? Also, if you use Eclipse you can press ctrl-shift-o to automatically import classes.

Comment: I imported it and still nothing. If I import that where would i place Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<String, Account>();?